# File upload does not return files within bootstrap modal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using a bootstrap modal dialog to upload a file. But when the form is submitted the $_FILES array does not contain any files.

here's my php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['saveButton']))
{
    $file = $_FILES['fileField']['name'];
}
```

here's my html code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form method="post" id="noteForm" name="noteForm" action="documentAndNotesList.php">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="file"  id="fileField" name="fileField" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" id="saveButton" name="saveButton" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add form`s enctype.

```
<form method="post" id="noteForm" name="noteForm" action="documentAndNotesList.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

[Reference:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)

Comment: @Yaza, can you please select my answer as solution then?

Answer (score 0):

When sending POST request with files you need to change encoding type to multipart. You do this with HTML attribute for `<form>` tag:

```
<form .. enctype="multipart/form-data">
```